# Publishing app under a different name from that of credit card

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, developer-program

I've recently completed a simple game, then I found out I need to be at least 18... No worries, you can let someone older publish it for you! Then how would anyone know it was ME who created it? Can my publisher register an apple ID with MY legal name but using their credit card / bank account and birthdate? Or can I use a different name (my name) when publishing it? Or can I at the very least write my name inside the game?

Comment: I've tried to edit this to be different than https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53395/ and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193651/ and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231089/  but it might still be duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Create a business entity, say "T.Miller Apps LLC" and publish under that. It will require legwork with forms and such.

There is no charge to transfer your membership but you will need to work with Developer support once you have established your LLC and gotten a D&B number.

I would expect 3 months of paperwork / emails and about $150 of legal filing fees to establish a US LLC properly with the correct registrations for Apple to accept it as a company. If you're handy with paperwork or can do all of it yourself, you might cut half the time and cost off.

Choosing which location to register will affect your costs and taxes so you might want to research that before transferring your program to an LLC.

Answer (score 1):

The publisher name needs to be correct in order to protect consumers. If Apple requires the publisher to be at least 18 years old, then you cannot write your name here, if you're not 18 yet.

You can however write your own name inside the game in a credits section or similar.